# How do i encrypt a file before uploading to a server?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am sending a file like this to the server:

```
  const fd = new FormData()
  const targetFile = document.getElementById('default_file').files[0]
  fd.append('file', targetFile )

  fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: fd,
  })
```

I want to be able to encrypt the file with a password before uploading (client-side)

i have tried this so far but i'm not sure where to go next:

```
  const targetFile = document.getElementById('default_file').files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(targetFile)
  reader.onload = () => {

    console.log(reader.result)
    const encrypted = CryptoJs.AES.encrypt(reader.result, "password123") <-- is this correct?

   //should i convert the encrypted part to something specific?
  }
```

reader.result returns the arraybuffer of the file, is it this part that i have to encrypt, and will the file stay in the same format so i can upload it to the server without changing code there?

Comment: HTTPS is not enough?

Comment: It's not about that. Just trying to understand this stuff before i go to college next month.

Comment: a file is simply a stream of bytes, no matter what format. if you encrypt it the result is still a stream of bytes (just scrambled aka "encrypted"). so instead of uploading the original bytes upload the encrypted bytes (by reading the original files arraybuffer or simply passing the arraybuffer or array of bytes to the encryption method and upload the result